# Viewing XML properly in Firefox 8.0

Tags: firefox, xml

[image: XML view]

How do I make this XML display properly on Firefox?
I want any addon or plugin or anything that will allow me to read this XML properly from the get-go (and hopefully enable me to expand/collapse nodes)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually already part of Firefox/Gecko. [See an example.](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/1165936105.xml) The problem is that it only works for XML documents – specifically `Content-Type: application/xml`. Your page is probably returning a `text/html` type, causing the browser to use a HTML parser.

Comment: No, Solr returns `application/xml`

Comment: The case is: firefox already shows xml documents in a neat readable way. Try http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/docs/SOAP_Requests/NDFDgen.xml and it will show up good. Otherwise, you have an addon overriding browser's default behavior

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable then copy the XML and paste it on **XMLSPY**

On **XMLSPY**, you can expand/collapse node in a better way.